# Spring Boot JUnit5: TypeCast Mocking

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Consider the below code,

```
JAXBElement<Response> jaxb=(JAXBElement<Response>) service.getResponse("abc",2000); //getResponse return an Object.

Response resp=jaxb.getValue(); // Null Pointer Exception
```

Now in JUnit I am mocking the "service.getResponse(...)"

```
@Mock
Service service;

when(service.getResponse(anyString(),anyInt()).thenReturn(new Response("value"));
```

Why am I getting NullPointerException here? Is this not the way to mock the given line?

Comment: Your service returns (as casted) JAXBElement<Response>? But mock returns Response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mock the response aswell.

```
JAXBElement<Response> jaxb=(JAXBElement<Response>) service.getResponse("abc",2000); //getResponse return an Object.

Response resp=jaxb.getValue(); // Null Pointer Exception
```

Junit here,

```
@Mock
Service service;

JAXBElement response = mock(JAXBElement.class);
when(service.getResponse(anyString(),anyInt()).thenReturn(response);
when(response.getValue()).thenReturn(something);
```